# Is this a good way to use NOT IN?

Tags: php, mysql

Let us Imagine the Facebook homepage. There is a list of posts, I report a post, and that post is blocked.

So, in the PHP & Mysql backend, I would do something like.

1. `reported_posts` = MySQL `GROUP_CONCAT(reported_post_id)` and fetch all my reported posts, store it in some cache like memcached or redis. This will give me a response with comma separated post_ids like `123, 234, 45`
2. Fetch all `homepage_posts` which are `NOT IN (reported_posts)`. This will give us all the `post_ids` that needs to be in the homepage other than the posts, 123, 234 and 45, as I have used `NOT IN`.

The issue here is that, as time goes by, the `reported_posts` will keep on increasing(lets assume it increases 1000 ids). At that time, the `NOT IN (reported_posts)` clause will take a huge input. Will this effect the performance of the query? What is an alternative solution to this?

I hope I could convey my doubt clearly, please let me know if it needs more clarification, I would edit as such. Thank you.

**EDIT**

The Reported post is not to be considered Globally, i.e. If I report the post, it should be Hidden only for me, and not for anyone else. So, it's also dependent on the account_id as well.

Comment: You can simply add a WHERE condition not to get reported posts. Like `WHERE reported_coulmn<>0`. Considering you've taken column for reported posts and its a Boolean value.

Comment: There's no reason to use a pivot table like this. It can be done, but you're going to take a performance hit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that `reported_posts` contains a list of user-specific blacklisted posts, it would be much better to do an **exclusive left join** and let the database handle everything:

```
SELECT *
FROM homepage_posts hp
LEFT JOIN
   reported_posts rp 
   ON hp.id = rp.post_id       
      AND rp.account_id = 123
WHERE 
   rp.id IS NULL
```

Comment: The table from where we get `reported_posts` contains a list of user-specific blacklisted posts i.e. it has columns `account_id` and `post_id`

Comment: Hi, not yet. I'll accept it when I get it done. This should work out. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In mysql "IN" operator works fine if the column is indexed. If that column is not indexed then it impacts performance.